# Textured Text with CSS?

Tags: css

I'm currently developing a simple page.

Does anyone know of any way to overlay a texture image over text? It seems like it's not possible with the current spec, but please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks and take care!

Answer (score 5):

Dunno why nobody ever answered this. This is possible using `background-clip`: https://codepen.io/Grsmto/pen/ZomWEj

Comment: ...because that is currently limited to a prefixed webkit-only solution.

Comment: ...no it's not. Works on every modern browsers.

Comment: You edited your answer... then replied as though I were commenting on the edited version. Your original was webkit-prefixed. Either way, like it or not, 12% market share still qualifies IE as a mainstream browser. Mobile support looks spotty too (you know, *as of writing this*). Bottom line, I don't think it's quite there yet.

Comment: I edited cause I assumed readers would be able to add the unprefixed version themselves.
You can also let the users choose whatever solution for this problem they want to adopt based on their target users. Instead of trying hard to make my answer look like a bad one (for what reason exactly?..). They are good to know if they want to support IE or not (also, heard of "progressive enhancement"?).

Comment: As long as people know that it's a no-go on IE and questionable on mobile, I'm happy. Nothing personal. Just sharing some useful info. :) In fact, I'd suggest adding it to the answer, but that's your call.

Comment: The answer was fine.  It's time to stop giving a crap about IE.  That way, once the last few people (~3%) still using IE either die off, or realize "the internet" doesn't work for them anymore, then they'll upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

You can't overlay an image over text with native CSS 2.1, That will not be implemented into CSS 3.0 either.  The best practice is to use a background image and still use your text in the `<h1>` tag and hide it with CSS.

```
<style>
h1 { background:url(images/imagepath.png) no-repeat; height:50px; width:300px; text-indent:-10000px; }
</style>

<body>
   <h1>Insert Text Here</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: This was what I was thinking too. Thanks for taking the effort to type out the html as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not with pure CSS alone, and certainly not in a cross browser compatible way. Best to just make it a transparent .png image.

Comment: Thanks - one can hope for a day where browsers play nicely together! 'Til then, take care.