# With css is it possible to use an image for text color?

Tags: css, image, text, colors

Can I make text textured by somehow setting an image as the text color, and having it repeat throughout the text?

Comment: If you need wide browser compatibility, you'll have to use JavaScript. Would you be interested in a JavaScript solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with pure css. See previous post on [Textured Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779490/textured-text-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible, sorry.

You'd need to make an image.

Though if you could create the text with [CSS masks](http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/), it will work :)

Comment: It is actually possible... `-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
background-image: url(your-image.jpg);`

Comment: @SamuelChen Probably wasn't back in 2011 though...

Comment: yeah haha only found that you can do this like a year ago xd

Comment: this didn't work for me. Could not find anything online about -webkit-background-clip either.

Comment: You can do it in canvas BTW

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can take a font of your choice and alter it so the outlines are cut out of solid blocks (like the 'oversteer' glyphs of [this image](http://www.dafont.com/img/preview/u/n/unsteady_oversteer0.png) instead of the 'unsteady' glyphs).  You can embed this custom font into pages [using CSS's @font-face](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator), and then it's just a matter of applying a background in the normal way (and ensuring proper line-height, etc.).