# Set background image for font color?

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following code:

```
<span>Hello world!</span>
```

And the following CSS:

```
span{
color:red;
}
```

Is there any way I can change the `red` to an image? Like `url(images/text-bg.png);`? I want to put a texture on my text and decided that I would just make the text "color" an image, but I'm not sure if this can be done with CSS.

Comment: I'm trying to think if there would be a way to do this using opacity; but I don't think there is.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference  Look around there at text and font styles available and see if there is anything to try and get the effect you're looking for without using an image.

Comment: You might be able to produce it with a bit of SVG...

Comment: possible duplicate of [With css is it possible to use an image for text color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812236/with-css-is-it-possible-to-use-an-image-for-text-color)

Comment: Okay, the "dupe" links back to here. Further more, I have a "minimal understanding of the problem being solved." I did not know, at the time, if this was possible, but I find there very far from off-topic. Since there is no regular CSS syntax for a background-image for text, I asked it here. Once again, I really do not think this deserves to be labeled as "off-topic."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible using svg , you can embed `<svg>` over one `<div>` and background image over another `<div>`, later apply z-index to `<div>`. You can use Vector applications like illustrator to create the svg the way you want.

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
html
 {
    background-image:url('lauch.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    padding-top:200px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div align="center">
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="140px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 76.25 39.167" enable-background="new 0 0 76.25 39.167" xml:space="preserve">
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 5.9336 30.417)" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" font-family="'Tahoma'" font-size="36">Text</text>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No point using svg when you can have an img. Unless you want to of course.

Answer (score 10):

it is possible, take a look at this pen here

https://codepen.io/feferonka/pen/eoWLZp

Use this on parent of text:

```
  background-image: url(url);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly fine for me

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
background-image: url(your-image.jpg);
```

Comment: This needs to be style on your h1 or your text in this case span.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, not even with CSS3. Here's an interesting article on text effects you can use with CSS3.

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/8-examples-of-stunning-css3-text-effects

Another option is to use a custom font which suites your needs.

This site has an amazing amount of free open-source fonts in every format needed to support all browsers, it even gives you a nice demo file to demonstrate how to implement it in CSS. This is compatible with CSS2.1 as well, making it IE7+ compatible.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

Comment: It seems like I achieve the same effect with the "zebra" example in the link you showed me.

Comment: Unfortunately, that example doesn't belong on that list. It's not CSS3, it's simply just uses image replacement as mentioned by @wex

Comment: Yeah, plus the background has to be the same color as the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The technique of swapping out text for images is common for headers and page navigation, but there really aren't any pure CSS techniques that are cross-browser compatible ([this](http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/07/24/pure-css-text-gradient-no-pngs/) is a nice technique, but isn't something you should rely on).

If you have a finite amount of text that you want to apply the texture to, your best bet is to just replace the text with images manually, as such:

HTML:

```
<h1 class="title">Title</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1.title { 
  background: url(images/title.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
  width: 80px;
  height: 23px;
  text-indent: -10000px; }
```

Comment: Here's the thing, I want to be able to change the text without having to go into PS and remake the header.

Comment: True. Again, I really only recommend this technique if you're using it for a "finite amount of text", and, as you said, text that can be expected to be static.