# Text with multiple color gradient in CSS

Tags: html, css, text, colors, gradient

How can one create, using CSS, a multi-color text just as in the picture below ?

[image: What I'm trying to do]

The text uses somehow randomly differents colors, and I'd like to make something that looks the same. This is from a picture so I can't just look for the answer in the page's source code.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Hi, I don't know if it answers exactly what you want, but seems to be related to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261680/set-background-image-for-font-color  and one of the answers links to a page with this: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: This is better done using SVG, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005447/cross-browser-text-gradient-in-pure-css-without-using-background-image

Answer (score 0):

```css
.gradient2:before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) radial-gradient(circle, #23966c, #faaa54, #e23b4a, #db0768, #360670) repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
.gradient2:before, .gradient2:after {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.gradient2:after {
    background: #04161f none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: white;
    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, aut.";
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.gradient2 {
    background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: black;
    margin: 1em auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #04161f, 1px -1px 0 #04161f, -1px -1px 0 #04161f, -1px 1px 0 #04161f;
    width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p class="gradient2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, aut.</p>
</body>
```